# Javascript - remove button and parent

Tags: javascript, select, html-lists

Hi I am just learning Javascript and after following some tutorials I thought it would be nice to practise some Javascript by making stuff.

So now I am trying to make a very easy to-do-list. Just for practise, but I get stuck.
I managed to add items with a remove-button to an UL with JS. But, BUT:

How do I make it so; when you click on the removeMe button, that only that Li will be removed?
What should I use?
Here's my code:

```
var buttonAdd = document.getElementById('but1');
var buttonRemove = document.getElementById('but2');

var ul = document.getElementById('myUl');

function addLi() {
var newLi = document.createElement('li');
var removeThis = document.createElement('button');
var textInput = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
if(textInput === ""){
 alert('Add text');
}else{
newLi.innerHTML = textInput;
newLi.appendChild(removeThis);
removeThis.innerHTML = "Remove me";
removeThis.setAttribute("onClick", "removeMe(this);");
ul.appendChild(newLi);
 }  
}

buttonAdd.onclick = function() {
 addLi(); 
};

buttonRemove.onclick = function() {
 ul.innerHTML = "";
};

function removeMe(item){
  //get called when clicked on the remove button
}
```

and my HTML:

```
<body>
 <ul id="myUl"></ul>
  <input id="inputText" type="text"><br />
  <button id="but1">Add stuff</button><br />
  <button id="but2">Remove all</button>
</body>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `remove()` is a [brand new DOM 4 method](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-dom-20131107/#dom-childnode-remove) and not very widely supported yet. The clunky, but bulletproof way would be:

```
function removeMe(item){
  item.parentElement.parentElement.removeChild(item.parentElement);
}
```

or with a bit more elegance:

```
function removeMe(item){
  var parent = item.parentElement;
  parent.parentElement.removeChild(parent);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BtbR4/

Also be careful with this:

```
removeThis.setAttribute("onClick", "removeMe(this);");
```

Handing a function reference as a string is always a bad idea for several reasons (eval'ing the string, messing up the scope). There are several better options:

```
removeThis.onclick = removeMe;
```

or if you need to hand over parameters

```
removeThis.onclick = function(){removeMe(your,parameters)};
```

The best option however is to [attach eventhandlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) always like this:

```
Element.addEventListener("type-of-event",functionReference);
```

Comment: The unique (messed up) scope of an `onclick` handler added via an attribute can certainly be confusing. But what do you mean by *"evaling the content"*?

Comment: @BlueSkies The string you pass as second parameter needs to be evaluated, which is very slow and might also a security risk.

Comment: Evaluated just once to be clear (some people seem to think it gets eval'd on every event), and its cost won't be noticed. Just wanted to clarify that. And no, there's no security risk if you hard coded the string in the code. At that point, it has no more risk than any other code that was written.

Comment: @BlueSkies You are wrong on that. It has impact on performance since strings cannot be optimized and compiled ahead by the browser engine. Also I talked about `eval` in general being a potential security risk and I cannot think of any usecase out of my head where you would need it in javascript.

Comment: Valid point about the inability to be optimized by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the parent node (the li), as [I've shown using jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uxAcESA/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

```
function removeMe(item){
    item.parentNode.remove();
}
```

Please note Blue Skies's comment that this may not work across all browsers, an alternative is:

```
var par = item.parentNode; par.parentNode.removeChild(par);
```

Comment: Jeez, that's it.. I was soooo close :) Thanks!

Comment: @MarekvanderHoeven: That will only work in a few modern browsers. The correct way to do this in a widely compatible manner is `var par = item.parentNode; par.parentNode.removeChild(par);`

Answer (score 0):

a cleaner way to do things is to add

```
removeThis.onclick = removeMe;
```

and

```
function removeMe(mouseEvent){
    this.parentNode.remove();
}
```

This is consistent with how you add the other onclick functions in your code. Since you said you are learning js, it is a good idea to learn how events and functions work. So, the take away from this is that the 'this' of a function that is attached to an object is the object itself (the removeThis object in this case), and event handlers give you access to the event that invoked them (mouseEvent) in the argument list.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QT4E3/

Comment: same problem as Shane's solution - remove is not very widely supported atm.